# Shell script to process service restart procedure

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos, awk

We're running a 3rd party TTY service on our servers, to support some thin clients manufactured by the 3rd party.

From time to time, connection to a thin client can get locked up. Procedure is to stop the TTY service, wait for connections to close, start the TTY service. Additionally on CentOS 4.x servers the command `init q`

Normally we do this manually like this, from root.

```
service axtty stop
```

Stop the service

```
netstat -d | grep axel
```

Run and monitor the netstat command until all connections are closed, ie. No lines containing `axel`.

```
service axtty start
```

Start the service

Is there a way to sum all that up in a single automated shell script (bash)?

Servers are CentOS 4.x or 6.x

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

service axtty stop

while netstat -d | grep -q axel ; do
  sleep 1
done

service axtty start
```

NOTE: With GNU `sleep`, you could do `sleep 0.1` or other floating point fraction of 1 second.